# Error when writing a test to check valid data in the database

Tags: java, mockito

I want to write a test in Mockito that will check that the data in the database is saved and saved correctly. That is, the data is correct, but I get an error
My code:

```
@Test
void contextLoads() {
    Worker worker = new Worker("Name", "reqwrqwe321412");
    workerService.create(worker);
    Mockito.doReturn(worker).when(workerService).create(worker);
    Mockito.verify(workerRepository, Mockito.times(1)).save(worker);
    Assertions.assertEquals(worker, workerRepository.findByName(worker.getName()));
}
```

Error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
 Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
  Example of correct stubbing:
   doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();
```

That is, I want to first save the value in the database, check that the saving occurred by checking the call of the save method, and then get an object from the database by name and compare it with the one that was recorded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same exception as you.

You need to write your test like below, and if you're going to test if the repository's method is called, then you need to use @InjectMock annotation with your "workerService" class and mock "workerRepository" class. Since it will not go to the DB, it should be mocked.

The test should be short and execute one functionality at a time. For the findByName test, you need to have another method in the service class and write another test to cover this as a unit test.

```
@Test
public void testCreateMethod() {
    Worker worker = new Worker("Name", "reqwrqwe321412");
    workerService.create(worker);
    Mockito.verify(workerRepository, Mockito.times(1)).save(worker);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A mock is an instance of a class generated on the fly. It implements the same interface as your original class but all the methods will return null.
Now for each of the methods that shall not return null you define what it should return if called with a specific set of parameters.
This definition of course only works on mocks, not on real objects.

The purpose is to allow testing e.g. the application without having an application. In that case you mock the driver, and you can then predefine how it should react, and you can check afterwards if the expected number of calls were made. But you would never mock the class under investigation.